# неудаляемые глобальные переменные QJSEngine на Qt6

Tags: c++, qt

Перехожу c QScriptEngine на QJSEngine (с Qt5 на Qt6).
Не могу найти возможность создать неудаляемую глобальную переменную в скрипте.
В старой версии я использовал:

```
QScriptValue scriptCurRow=engine.newQObject( &row, QScriptEngine::QtOwnership );
engine.globalObject().setProperty( "current_row", scriptCurRow, QScriptValue::ReadOnly | QScriptValue::Undeletable );
```

Но в новой версии нет ни `QJSEngine::QtOwnership` (возможно, ненужен?), ни `QJSValue::ReadOnly`, ни `QJSValue::Undeletable`.

Существуют ли неудаляемые переменные в QJSEngine вообще?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjsengine.html#setObjectOwnership

Comment: QJSEngine::CppOwnership 0 The object is owned by C++ code and the JavaScript memory manager will never delete it. The JavaScript destroy() method cannot be used on these objects. This option is similar to QScriptEngine::QtOwnership

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Да, спасибо. это часть ответа. Я не нашел его потому что искал в `QJSEngine` -5й версии Qt (там эта функция находилась в `QQmlEngine`).

Comment: QScriptValue  уже давно отмечен как устаревший, вместо него используется QJSValue  - думаю, что ReadOnly и Undeleted не имеют значения, поэтому их и убрали. Почему, точно не знаю, но догадываюсь )